# Probability math debate

Tags: probability

So me and a friend else were having a debate recently. And I thrive to get a good answer to explain who's right.

So it's mainly about doubling someone's chances.

Here's the situation: There are 10 people at a party, and they all place their names (on a piece of paper) in a hat. The host of said party (who is included in the 10 people) is a nasty cheater and wants to double his chances. So he places his name in twice.

My friend claims that he Successfully doubled his chances because everybody else's chances are at 1/11 and his is 2/11, and 2/11 = 1/11 * 2.

But my logic goes as follows: he originally had 1/10 chance. Double that is 2/10. But by adding his name in twice he also increased the amount of names, so his new chance is 2/11. But 2/11 < 2/10, so he increased it by LESS than 2x.

Either my logic is really messed up, or his is. Who's correct.

Comment: is the 1/12 a typo? Please explain where 12 comes from.

Comment: @user2740 Yes, fixed it lol

Comment: The host's chance is originally 10%..  If your friend is right, then by putting in *ten* slips, the host can multiply his chance by 10 ---  making it 100%.  Ask your friend if he believes the host can *guarantee* himself a win by putting in ten slips.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is really more in semantics than anything else.

In the first case, the host has 1/10 chance of his name being pulled, like everyone else.

In the second case, the host has 2/11 chance in his name being pulled, while everyone else has 1/11 chance of their name being pulled.

While in the first case the host has the same chance as everyone else of winning, in the second game the host has *twice as much* chance as everyone else of winning.  So in some sense, the host did "double" his chance of winning **relative to everyone else**.

But to say he **doubled his original chances** would be false, since as you said doubling his original chances would mean he has a 2/10 chance of winning.  So he didn't double his original chances, but in the second game he has double the chance of winning as everyone else.

Comment: Thank you, you really cleared it up for me.

Comment: @warspyking You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you're half right. "Doubling his chances" should be relative to the chance *he* had previously. But $2/11 < 2/10$, so his chance increased *less* than double. That's the half where you were wrong.

"Doubling your chances" is a phrase similar to "doubling your money."
It doesn't matter what chances (or what money) someone else has before or
after you double yours; what matters is what *you* had before, and what
*you* had after.

Consider the scenario where the host puts in one extra slip with his name on it,
and $19$ additional slips with the words "everyone loses". Now his chance to win
is certainly twice as much as everyone else's--it's $1/15$, whereas they each have a $1/30$ chance--but his chance of winning is actually less than he
started out with: $1/15 < 1/10$.
I can't speak for anyone else, but if I a have the opportunity to double
my chances at something, I want to end up with better chances than I had
before I "doubled" them.